# World view does not display face/vert count

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

I started working on something in a new scene and for some reason the total face/tri/vertex count for everything in the layer i am on is not showing. This never happened before, is there a way to fix it?

[image]

Comment: for example linked groups don't show face/tri/vertex counts.

Answer (score 3):

The vertex count uses objects in visible *render* layers. If you are on a layer which is not visible in the scene renderlayers, then this is what happens.

[image]

This is because the info panel displays scene wide information, but the visible viewport layers can be different between multiple viewports.

Since the viewport layers are locked to the scene layers by default, this doesn't happen all the time.